# UIManager strings

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, nimbus, uimanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location of String keys in L&F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519951/location-of-string-keys-in-lf)

This here is a line in my code:

```
UIManager.getString("FileChooser.saveButtonText", l);
```

This will return a `string` that represents text printed on save button of `JFileChooser`

Where does it fetch that `string` from?
I tried digging around src.zip, but I couldn't find it...

Comment: See also a previous question on this topic: [Location of String keys in L&F](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519951/location-of-string-keys-in-lf)

Answer (score 1):

1. have look at (methods are protected, then not accesible from outside)

   - [JButton getDefaultButton(JFileChooser fc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicFileChooserUI.html#getDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JFileChooser%29)
   - [Method Summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicFileChooserUI.html)
2. better way(my view) could be to ignore `BasicXxxUI` and to derive `JFileChooser` to the elements, that returns `JFileChooser`s `JComponent`s
3. look for [Custom JFilechooerUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720957/creating-custom-jfilechooser) and [another list of methods](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJFileChooserLookandFeel.htm)

Comment: See also [*How can I add localization to `JFileChooser` for a locale that is not supported by default*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3671868/230513)?