# Swing translation library

Tags: java, swing, localization

I have looked and could not find a library that would deal with problem of licalizating the swing component data.

Thus, I decided to create my own and make it public...

Only problem is that I don't really know where the language strings are contained...

If anyone would be so nice to tell me where to look in src folder, I'd be more than happy to create a library that would work something like this:

```
libraryClassName.JFileChooser.setJFileChooserStringValue(string);
```

`Swing` is mentioned in `com/sun/java` folder, and it's in `javax` folder too. There are many classes that include the names of swing components per component (`JFileChooser.java`, `FileChooserUI.java`, `BasicFileChooserUI.java`, `MetalFileChooserUI.java`, `MultiFileChooserUI.java`, `FileChooserPainter.java`, etc) and many more general classes that may or may not contain string vaules needed for localization.

I guess, when string values for one component are found, all the others should be in corresponding location.

So, if you help me with this, I'll make a library that will ease the sufferings of so many programmers that are trying to translate their programs...

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** Is the JFileChooser the only swing component that has predefined strings in it?

Comment: `Is the JFileChooser the only`, not it isn't

Comment: [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533253/uimanager-strings/12534449#12534449)

Comment: What other components contain predefined string in them?

Comment: part of compound JComponents has default label or default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I will try not to be lazy and help you with this one:

The file /src/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicFileChooserUI.java has nice method called installStrings (line 282), which contains what you are after:

```
protected void installStrings(JFileChooser fc) {

        Locale l = fc.getLocale();
        newFolderErrorText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.newFolderErrorText",l);
        newFolderErrorSeparator = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.newFolderErrorSeparator",l);

        newFolderParentDoesntExistTitleText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.newFolderParentDoesntExistTitleText", l);
        newFolderParentDoesntExistText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.newFolderParentDoesntExistText", l);
// ...
}
```

It seems that what you actually need to find is a call to `UIManager.getString(String, Locale)`, which seems to contain the key you are looking for. The actual method definition might reveal even more secrets, but I am too lazy to check it out ;)

Comment: Well, I guess that are all of the strings inside a JFileChooser, default values and more I can get by experiemnting...

I guess this is all to it...

Comment: Following the method, you get to a dead-end, I think...

But I am very interested to find the variable that holds the value of the actuall string...

Comment: Yes, it is a bit tricky. I also recall, that you have to set the translations before constructing the JFileChooser, which was the primary reason I decided to subclass it. Unfortunately, the whole Swing API is rather ugly (and I am speaking from experience). It will give you a headache...

Comment: So, once a JFileChooser is constructed, in order to change the language, you would have to dispose it and construct a new one?

Comment: It seems so. But it is not a problem with desktop applications. You actually should use system language via `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY)`. Sometimes, somebody might change system language on the fly, but it will be a corner case.